# Convergent series involving a product in the summand

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Numerical evidence suggests that
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\log_{2}(t)-1}\frac{2^m}{\prod_{k=m}^{\log_{2}(t)-1}(1-2^{k}w)} =\frac{-1}{w}$$
for any nonzero complex number $w$ such that $1\neq 2^{k}w$. Is there a way to prove this rigorously?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_0=1$ and for every $m\gt 0$
$$p_m=\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}(1-2^kw)$$
Then $p_{m+1}=(1-2^mw)p_m$ for every $m\in\Bbb N$.
Consequently, $p_{m+1}-p_m=-w2^mp_m$ from which
$$p_{t+1}-1=\sum_{m=0}^t(p_{m+1}-p_m)=-w\sum_{m=0}^t2^mp_m$$
If $w\neq 0$ and $w\neq 2^{-k}$ for every $k\in\Bbb N$, then $p_t\to\infty$ as $t\to\infty$, hence we get
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=0}^t\frac{2^m}{\prod_{k=m}^t(1-2^{k}w)}
&=\sum_{m=0}^t\frac{2^mp_m}{p_{t+1}}\\
&=-\frac 1w\frac{p_{t+1}-1}{p_{t+1}}\\
&=-\frac 1w\left(1-\frac 1{p_{t+1}}\right)\\
&\xrightarrow{t\to+\infty}-\frac 1w
\end{align}